# How do you document the xml structure of a REST API Call?

Tags: rest

Like SOAP which as a WSDL which allows you generate code that will help create request, is there any mechanism in REST which allows you to document the payload or response of a REST API call?

Most services that provide REST APIs, seem to provide samples to explain the structure.
What is the best practice for REST APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're returning xml, you can simply provide an xsd. There is also wadl, which some frameworks will generate automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I find the best practice is providing samples (or links to samples) to explain the structure. Developers working against your API then need no extra tools or workflows to know how to interact with each part of your service.